# Opposite of "svn up"?

Tags: svn

I have a SVN repository on a server, in /var/svn/repository, and a couple of working copies on the server, one 'staging' and one 'live'. Local dev working copies are sent to the server with 'svn commit' in the normal way.

I have a couple of simple two-line scripts on the server, that go to the appropriate location and do an 'svn update' to refresh the contents to the latest repository version.

- uplive:

  ```
  cd /usr/local/lib/Catalyst/proj/trunk
  svn up && echo 'go to proj.example.com to see changes'
  ```
- upstage:

  ```
  cd ~/Catalyst/svn/proj
  svn up && echo 'go to proj.example.com:3001 to see changes'
  ```

I would like to make a couple of companion scripts 'downstage' and 'downlive' but the closest thing I can find in svn requires a variable argument for the revision number:
examples I found include things like

$ svn merge -r HEAD:nnnn .

or

$ svn merge -c -303 http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk
--- Reverse-merging r303 into 'integer.c':

I am trying to come up with a simple way to do the "D'Oh!" function, i.e. undo the last svn update, that can be invoked through a script: e.g. ssh theServer downstage to undo the last 'svn up' and return the live/staging system to the previous rev.

No doubt it's possible to get the latest version from SVN,
take one away, and ask SVN to do a reverse-merge, but it seems like it is such an obvious thing to want to do that I am a bit surprised there's not a quicker/simpler way.

Comment: I can't remember ever wanting to do the precise thing you describe. First of all, my "D'oh!" moments after an update always involve wanting to get back local changes unmolested by a merge, and my IDE's "local history" feature takes care of that one. SVN can't help, as it won't have any copies of those locally modified files. Secondly, after an update, your local copy doesn't know what revisions the files were at prior to the last update; if an update brought some files up by three versions, you'd probably want to go back three, not one, right? But SVN doesn't know.

Comment: Good points both. I failed to be clear in my OP, that in this scenario the working copy is the live or staging server copy which will (or certainly _should_ ) never have any local modifications made, but always and only be a pristine copy of what has been committed into the repo from developers' working copies elsewhere. So there won't be _local_ mods; however the second point is definitely valid and means I need to go back to the feature requestor I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about doing an update to the previous revision with:

```
svn up -r PREV
```

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks. I had not encountered 'PREV' in the docs - at least, I didn't recall it. But I think that I may have an issue: Commit r99; svn up to stage and then to live; commit r100; svn up to stage; commit r101; commit r102; svn up to stage; commit r103; svn up to stage and then to live; then find the lurking bug and want to 'svn down' the live server to its last known good state which in this example is 99 not 102 ;-( Seems like doing some kind of backup outside svn may be necessary after all; although Alvaro's idea of branching could be a runner too. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

Updating a working copy is by no means a deterministic operation. Your working copy can be at any random state either before and after. If you want to undo an update you need to create a backup first. Something as simple as tar+gz should suffice.

If you want to make svn-only predictable updates you'll probably have to create branches and commit/merge stuff into them prior to updating. Of course, that won't take care either of non-versioned stuff.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you really want is something analogous to `git stash` - a capability to store your arbitrary working copy changes and isolate them from updates from the repository.

Here's one way to do it:

http://www.benrady.com/2009/09/svn-replacement-for-git-stash.html

and some scripts:

http://www.blisted.org/blog/bin/svn/stash

Comment: Hey, those are very clever and a little bit cheeky ;-) .. Thanks!